# Scala weird type when coercing parameterize method into a function?

Tags: scala, methods

Can't possibly read the following type return by the REPL

```
def  returnfuncdefGen[A] = (i: A) => i.toString.length

returnfuncdefGen: [A]=> A => Int
```

while i do understand that

```
def  returnfuncdefGen[A](i: A) = i.toString.length

returnfuncdefGen: [A](i: A)Int
```

The first version is what the author of FP simplified (scala) call **coercing parameterize method into a function**

> How exactly does one read this **[A]=> A => Int** ?

Also I find the notion of coercion a bit weird. It feels to me like creating a parentheless method that return a function. Now the generic on top i can't explain other by saying that the literal function does a closure of the type defined by the method.

Overall if someone could clarify to me what is happening and how to read that type  ****[A]=> A => Int**** that would really help.

Comment: I don’t think this is coercion. It’s simply a method that returns a function

Comment: I guess the question refers to this page https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book-diffs-val-def-scala-functions/ (section "Coerce a parameterized method into a function")

Comment: I guess in Scala language specification there is no notion "coercion" (although there are coercions for example in Haskell). Transformation of `def  returnfuncdefGen[A](i: A) = i.toString.length` into `def returnfuncdefGen[A] = (i: A) => i.toString.length` is similar to η-reduction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#%CE%B7-reduction

Comment: Fat arrows are right associative (I think), so you can imagine parens around A => Int. Also, adding an empty parameter list to the first Method may help you

Comment: But ethod return type notation never uses arrow. Why is it that in this case it does     
 ``` [A] => .....``` usual is it is either parentheis or simmply nothing and just the return type. Why not ```[A] Int => Int ?```

Comment: which is exactly what is being returned. Example ```def  returnfuncdef = (i: int) => i.toString.length``` this gives me ```returnfuncdef: Int => Int``` in the REALP

Comment: If i do ```def  returnfuncdefGen[A](i: A) = i.toString.length``` this gives me ```returnfuncdefGen: [A](i: A)Int```

Comment: So do you understand the issue with the notation now ? method do not use arrow for their return type.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. You want it to be [A](A) => Int?

Comment: Yup that’s right. It is just consistent with the rest that way

Comment: @MaatDeamon Actually starting from 2.13.2 it prints as you want. See details in my answer.

Comment: Ah nice, many thanks. Still on 2.12 :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Until Scala 2.13.1, I believe the notational difference is by design as per [SLS 3.3.1 Method Types](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#method-types)

> A method type is denoted internally as (Ps) ... A special case are
> types of methods without any parameters. They are written here => T.

Because method `returnfuncdefGen` is without any parameters, then its type is represented using `=> T` notation

```
scala> def  returnfuncdefGen[A] = (i: A) => i.toString.length
def returnfuncdefGen[A] => A => Int
```

where `T = A => Int`

See Dmytro's answer for changes in Scala 2.13.2 by [11416 MethodType.toString prints in scala format #7798](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7798/commits/44955a6cfe59b4b1a06c5210cb4d7330f429ea0d#diff-ecaa4198a04261cd0e00a708b695eafbR2950)

Comment: Cool. Sources were changed in 2.13.2, but specification wasn't. See details in my answer.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Dotty still seems to print it in the old way.

Answer (score 5):

If you do

```
object App {
  def returnfuncdefGen[A] = (i: A) => i.toString.length
  def returnfuncdefGen1[A]() = (i: A) => i.toString.length
  def returnfuncdefGen2[A](i: A) = i.toString.length
}

def printSignature(name: String): Unit = {
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  val t = typeOf[App.type].decl(TermName(name)).typeSignature
  println(s"t=$t, showRaw(t)=${showRaw(t)}")
}

printSignature("returnfuncdefGen")
printSignature("returnfuncdefGen1")
printSignature("returnfuncdefGen2")
```

you'll see

```
t=[A]=> A => Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), NullaryMethodType(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Function1, List(TypeRef(NoPrefix, TypeName("A"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))))
t=[A]()A => Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), MethodType(List(), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Function1, List(TypeRef(NoPrefix, TypeName("A"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))))
t=[A](i: A)Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), MethodType(List(TermName("i")), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))
```

That's because for `NullaryMethodType` `toString` was defined as `=>`

```
override def safeToString: String = "=> "+ resultType
```

Maybe you wanted it to be defined as `""` but that was not the case till 2.13.1 (including).

In 2.13.2 for `NullaryMethodType` `toString` was changed to `""`

```
override def safeToString: String = resultType.toString
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/internal/Types.scala#L2953

So now in 2.13.2, 2.13.3 the above code prints

```
t=[A]A => Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), NullaryMethodType(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Function1, List(TypeRef(NoPrefix, TypeName("A"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))))
t=[A](): A => Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), MethodType(List(), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Function1, List(TypeRef(NoPrefix, TypeName("A"), List()), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))))
t=[A](i: A): Int, showRaw(t)=PolyType(List(TypeName("A")), MethodType(List(TermName("i")), TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())))
```

as you wanted.

By the way, in Dotty 0.26.0-bin-20200703-2dd1c93-NIGHTLY

```
def returnfuncdefGen[A] = (i: A) => i.toString.length
def returnfuncdefGen1[A]() = (i: A) => i.toString.length
def returnfuncdefGen2[A](i: A) = i.toString.length
def returnfuncdefGen3 = [A] => (i: A) => i.toString.length
def returnfuncdefGen4() = [A] => (i: A) => i.toString.length

>....def returnfuncdefGen[A] => A => Int
>....def returnfuncdefGen1[A](): A => Int
>....def returnfuncdefGen2[A](i: A): Int
>....def returnfuncdefGen3: PolyFunction{apply: [A](i: A): Int}
>....def returnfuncdefGen4(): PolyFunction{apply: [A](i: A): Int}
```

Answer (score 3):

`[A] => A => Int` is a function with a type parameter of `A` and no arguments which returns a function `A => Int

This is different to `def  returnfuncdefGen[A](i: A) = i.toString.length` which is a function with a type parameter of `A` and a single argument of type `A` which returns an `Int`

Comment: Taking your first paragraph would mean that there is a coercion happening ? Def is coerced into a function ? Otherwise why is it not a method of type a with no argument that return a function ?

Comment: This is so strange because ```def returnfuncdef = (i: Int) => i + 2``` does not coerce anything ? Does it ? the type here is  Int => Int. Which to me is a method that is parentheless and return a function.

Comment: *"`[A] => A => Int` is a function ..."*, *"`def  returnfuncdefGen[A](i: A) = i.toString.length` which is a function ..."* More precisely, not a function but method.

Comment: Ok got it. I guess the typing for that is a bit inconsistent with the how method or function are usually type in the`` REALP: [A] => .....``  is strange, it does not follow the typical method typing notation which do not use ```=>```

Comment: Neither are functions, both are methods. But the first method returns a function. The differences between functions and methods are very important, specially for newcomers. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala) for a detailed explanation of the differences.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes fully agree, the only issue is the notation. usually method do not use arrow for their return type. But in this case it does. The function returned is ```A => Int``` but then you have ```[A] => A => Int```, in other words, ```[A] => ````  is about the method and that is where my issue is. I agree, i just think the notation is wrong.